# Unable to recover from optimistic locking failure

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm deleting all objects from my Model, except certain objects which the user has interacted with.

After deleting I fetch those saved objects and update their information, from a JSON, and when I save the managedContext the app crashes printing 'Unable to recover from optimistic locking failure.'

I've been looking but I haven`t found any information on what this message means, any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I implemented a custom merge policy based on an attribute `updatedAt` for various entities. Some entities, however, did not have this attribute, and I forgot to call `try super.resolve(optimisticLockingConflicts: [conflict])` for these conflicts.  Thus `resolve(optimisticLockingConflicts` was called repeatedly until CoreData gave up and logged `Unable to recover from optimistic locking failure`.
After I called `super` for these cases, the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Google first result, documentation from Apple. (Where exactly have you been "looking"?)

> Problem: You see the error message, "Could not merge changes".
>
> Cause: Two different managed object contexts tried to change the same data. This is also known as an **optimistic locking failure**.
>
> Remedy: Either set a merge policy on the context, or manually (programmatically) resolve the failure. You can retrieve the currently committed values for an object using committedValuesForKeys:, and you can re-fault the object (so that when it is next accessed its data values are retrieved from its persistent store) using refreshObject:mergeChanges:.

Even though the error message is different, this sounds very much like your case, for you most likely have multiple contexts that try to modify the same objects.
Try setting the merge policy to `NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType`.

Comment: That's the thing, I dont have 2 managed contexts, and I already have set up the policy 'NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy'

Comment: Maybe you are accessing the objects to *update* in your routine that handles the JSON information. This could potentially be in another thread - so you should perhaps create a child context to handle the update and then push up to the parent context. Conceptually, it is still the same problem.

Comment: Same thing! Still doesn't work.
@subharb Did you get it working some way?

Answer (score 0):

I have this error due to trying to save a model that violates a uniqueness constraint on the database.  The following sql is executed many times (1005) in/with one context until it fails with the "CoreData: error: fatal: Unable to recover from optimistic locking failure." message:

```
2016-08-10 23:20:50.613 DtLoad[49506:78762894] CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZSAMPLE(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZR, ZUSER, ZW) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2016-08-10 23:20:50.613 DtLoad[49506:78762894] CoreData: sql: ROLLBACK
2016-08-10 23:20:50.613 DtLoad[49506:78762894] CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
```

XCode Version 7.3.1

Answer (score 0):

If you are still getting this error even though you have dutifully set a merge policy, it could be you are testing a **corrupt Core Data SQLite store**.

My apps have some code to check for inconsistencies such as a orphaned objects in the object graph.  To test this code, I edited a Core Data SQLite store using a sqlite editor, adding an orphaned object.  But I neglected to change the value in the `Z_OPT` column from its default value of 0.  Well, according an [astute reverse engineer](https://www.iphonelife.com/blog/31369/unleash-your-inner-app-developer-core-data-behind-scenes), Z_OPT indicates the number of times an object has been changed, *starting with 1* when it is initially added to the database.  0 is therefore an illegal value, and Core Data reacts by declaring an *optimistic locking failure*.  Changing that value to 1 fixed it.